# I can't use selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

THIS IS MY CODE

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

print 0

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

print 1

browser.get("http://www.baidu.com") 

browser.close()
```

And I can't open the url.

the broswer is open and the url is null.

and the broswer is stuck.

and then I found the code can print 0 and can't print 1

what's wrong?!

How to see If my Firefox is compatible with my selenium 
my selenium is 2.42.1
my firefox is 31.0

Comment: your Firefox version might not be compatible with selenium.Check the docs .

Comment: Your code works flawlessly. Check your Firefox, or your internet settings...

Comment: How to see If my Firefox is compatible with my selenium

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: Firefox 31 is not officially supported by Selenium. Please downgrade until we get a new selenium release.